# Javascript/jQuery function fadeIn/out on mouse over/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a php/mysql(+css jquery etc.) project where i have to make a function that shows up a little description when mouse is over an image.
I did a function but it seems to crash after 2-3 times i use it(when i go with mouse over the image)
Here is a part of code and jsfiddle :
**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/c7d8g/ 
 
**Code :**
*html* :

```
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="cover" src="http://www.unheap.com/wp-content/uploads/Blindify.png" />
        <div class="coverDetail">
            This by default is hidden
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <a class="title" href="#">About this card</a>
            <p class="text">Description of this card.</p>
            <p class="author">@alex</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*css*:

```
.card {
    background: #0e0e0e;
    color:#a4a4a4;
    width:250px;
    height:320px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.cover {
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:140px;
    background: transparent;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.coverDetail {
    position:absolute;
    width:220px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top: 114px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #e8ff28;
    border-top: 1px solid #ecf97e;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:100;
}
.description {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    display: block;
    margin-top:150px;
}
.title {
    color:#b4b4b4;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title:hover {
    color:#62c6ff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d9f1ff;
}
.text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-height: 85px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width:90%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.author, a {
    bottom: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

*js function that i did but is crashing* :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cover").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
    });
    $(".cover").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).next().stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

*My question*:
I need a function to work perfectly, fadeIn the "coverDetail" element from the card where user hovers on cover image. And when users mouseout of the cover image, coverDetail of the specific card should fadeOut .
*I have about 150 cards / page and i need the function to work good for every single card*
Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by "crashing" ?
what exactly is happening ?

Comment: When i'm going with my cursor over cover image everything works fine, my "coverDetail" shows up but if i continue to go down with my cursor to card description, funtion get stuck with coverDetail state of hidden..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer to use `.hover()` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7d8g/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".card").hover(function () {
        $(".coverDetail", this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(".coverDetail", this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Note there are some minor changes to your css in the fiddle.

Comment: The description of the card is always showing.. i want only coverDetail to fade in or out when user is with cursor over the cover image..

Comment: @Alexandru Ahhh okay, i will change it now :)

Comment: And another thing, this function should fadeIn or out coverDetail of the specific cover image of the card user is hovering at. That means function should work if i have multiple cards on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the update but look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/c7d8g/11/ . Is still wrong, just hover over a card in this jsfiddle and see what happens with coverDetails of all cards not just the one i'm hovering at..

Answer (score 1):

You need first to hide the description:
Add the following snippet to your `CSS` code:

```
.coverDetail {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you need to use the following code to show and hide the description for each card separately:

```
$(function () {
    $(".cover")
        .mouseout(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('.coverDetail').fadeOut();
    })
        .mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('.coverDetail').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

And here is the example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X25NF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this
Css:

```
.coverDetail {
    position:absolute;
    width:220px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top: 114px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #e8ff28;
    border-top: 1px solid #ecf97e;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:100;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cover').hover(function(){
            $('.coverDetail').stop().fadeIn()
            },function(){
                $('.coverDetail').stop().fadeOut()
        })

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set the hover event on the card and run an animation

```
.coverDetail {
    position:absolute;
    width:220px;
    height:0px;
    margin-top: 114px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: #e8ff28;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:100;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.card').hover(function(){
            $('.coverDetail').stop().css({'border-top':'1px solid #ecf97e'}).animate({'height':'25px'},1000)
            },function(){
            $('.coverDetail').stop().css({'border-top':'0px'}).animate({'height':'0px'},1000)
        })
    }); 
</script>
```